# Filter data in a list(List1) using a inputMap(key and values may vary for each request)

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String birthDate;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zipCode;    
}

Map<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
inputMap.put(“name”, “David”);

Map<String, String> inputMap1 = new HashMap<>();
inputMap1.put(“name”, “David”);
inputMap1.put(“city”, “Auburn”);
```

I’ll get List of Persons from DB and below map is the input (this inputMap is dynamic. We may get just city or city & zipCode or any combination of the above 5 properties defined in Person object)

I need to filter List of Persons matching with the inputMap using streams. I tried different ways using java stream but no luck, please help.

Comment: it may help if you can show what you tried and didn't worked for you.

Comment: Here some examples to use sreams with filter

https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/?utm_source=mkyong.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=afterpost-related&utm_content=link0

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter for each possible key in the `Map` (i.e. you'll need 5 `filter` operations):

```
List<Person> input = ...

List<Person> filtered = input.stream()
                             .filter(p -> !inputMap.containsKey("name") || p.getName().equals(inputMap.get("name")))
                             .filter(p -> !inputMap.containsKey("city") || p.getCity().equals(inputMap.get("city")))
                             ...
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to generalize this for an arbitrary number of `Map` keys, you'll need another `Map` that maps the keys to corresponding properties of the `Person`.

For example, if you had a:

```
Map<String,Function<Person,Object>> propMap = new HashMap<>();
propMap.put ("name",Person::getName);
propMap.put ("city",Person::getCity);
...
```

You could write:

```
List<Person> filtered = input.stream()
                             .filter(p -> inputMap.entrySet()
                                                  .stream()
                                                  .allMatch(e -> propMap.get(e.getKey()).apply(p).equals(e.getValue())))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This means that for each key of `inputMap`, the corresponding property of a `Person` instance (which is obtained via `propMap.get(key).apply(p)` where `p` is the `Person`) must be equal to the value of that key.